# Python- How to update a list of a list of a list

Tags: python, list, nested, sublist

I'm actually trying to do this dynamically, but for now I was just hoping to get a static example as the code snippets I've found so far, don't appear to work for lists this deeply nested (or I am misunderstanding how to apply the syntax).

From a static point of view, I am attempting to update the 'runner' sub-list of the 'runners' sub-list (which is then part of market_book and ultimately market_books), so I thought this would work:

```
market_books[0].runners[0].x = 'test'
    setattr(market_books[0].runners[0], 'y', 'test2')
    print(market_books[0].runners[0].x, market_books[0].runners[0].y)
    print(market_books[0].json())
```

Now, the first print displays exactly as expected (i.e. it shows test test2), however when I attempt to print the next level up, it hasn't updated, therefore I assume I'm not actually updating it, but merely assigning a value to the sub-list.

The full dataset is as follows:

```
{"marketId":"1.130856098","totalAvailable":null,"isMarketDataDelayed":null,"lastMatchTime":null,"betDelay":0,"version":2576584033,"complete":true,"runnersVoidable":false,"totalMatched":null,"status":"OPEN","bspReconciled":false,"crossMatching":false,"inplay":false,"numberOfWinners":1,"numberOfRunners":10,"numberOfActiveRunners":8,"runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":2.8,"size":4},{"price":2.78,"size":20},{"price":2.76,"size":22}],"availableToLay":[{"price":2.82,"size":11.94},{"price":2.84,"size":9.45},{"price":2.86,"size":66.97}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832765},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":18.5,"size":2},{"price":18,"size":5},{"price":17.5,"size":2.7}],"availableToLay":[{"price":19.5,"size":2.44},{"price":20,"size":10},{"price":21,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832767},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":12.5,"size":1.27},{"price":12,"size":14.96},{"price":11.5,"size":39.62}],"availableToLay":[{"price":15.5,"size":2},{"price":16,"size":15.18},{"price":16.5,"size":3.26}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832766},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":26,"size":1},{"price":25,"size":4},{"price":24,"size":2}],"availableToLay":[{"price":30,"size":2.22},{"price":32,"size":2},{"price":34,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832769},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":15,"size":4},{"price":14.5,"size":3},{"price":14,"size":5.77}],"availableToLay":[{"price":17,"size":2},{"price":17.5,"size":2},{"price":18,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832768},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":4.9,"size":51.43},{"price":4.8,"size":66.63},{"price":4.7,"size":43.31}],"availableToLay":[{"price":5,"size":108.94},{"price":5.1,"size":20},{"price":5.2,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832771},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":20,"size":6},{"price":19.5,"size":2},{"price":19,"size":2}],"availableToLay":[{"price":22,"size":2},{"price":23,"size":2},{"price":24,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832770},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":6.2,"size":8.04},{"price":6,"size":80.47},{"price":5.9,"size":2}],"availableToLay":[{"price":6.4,"size":69.24},{"price":6.6,"size":46},{"price":6.8,"size":102.33}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":10064909}],"publishTime":1552066850090,"priceLadderDefinition":{"type":"CLASSIC"},"keyLineDescription":null,"marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false,"turnInPlayEnabled":false,"persistenceEnabled":false,"marketBaseRate":5,"eventId":"28180290","eventTypeId":"2378961","numberOfWinners":1,"bettingType":"ODDS","marketType":"NONSPORT","marketTime":"2019-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","suspendTime":"2019-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","bspReconciled":false,"complete":true,"inPlay":false,"crossMatching":false,"runnersVoidable":false,"numberOfActiveRunners":8,"betDelay":0,"status":"OPEN","runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":1,"id":10064909},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":2,"id":12832765},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":3,"id":12832766},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":4,"id":12832767},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":5,"id":12832768},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":6,"id":12832770},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":7,"id":12832769},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":8,"id":12832771},{"status":"LOSER","sortPriority":9,"id":10317013},{"status":"LOSER","sortPriority":10,"id":10317010}],"regulators":["MR_INT"],"countryCode":"GB","discountAllowed":true,"timezone":"Europe\/London","openDate":"2019-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","version":2576584033,"priceLadderDefinition":{"type":"CLASSIC"}}}
```

I have the dynamic code I use (i.e. a couple of for loops, however to avoid confusion, if someone would be kind enough to help with the static syntax I will then try to apply it myself to the dynamic code, otherwise I'm sort of asking for 2 solutions in one)!

Comment: What is the type of `market_books[0]`? I'm not aware of any built-in types that have a json() method.

Comment: market_books is a custom class (I have no control over how I receive this unfortunately). Not sure how best to explain the structure, other than this is how I would iterate:  
```for market_book in market_books:  
        for runner in market_book.runners:  ```
  
Also the 'dataset' in the original question is the copy-paste of the .json() output.

Comment: Well, at the very least I can tell you that your attribute assignment statements look fine, and I would completely expect them to update your object the way you were hoping it would. So the problem most likely lies within the custom class. Maybe `.json` is disregarding the `runners` attribute and generating the data from scratch, or something. It's hard to say without seeing the class definition.

Comment: Okay cool thank you, maybe that is the case. At least if my logic is okay that helps, I can always create a new list I guess, rather than trying to update the troublesome custom class!

Comment: Whilst I haven't found a solution, it seems that this behaviour may well be expected, it seems each object is a different id (i.e. id(market_books[0]...), so when I print the parent list python sees this as a separate object, hence it hasn't updated.

That of course doesn't help me solve the issue...but perhaps someone may be able to advise how I can adjust the code to ensure I'm updating the same object each time?